# .sqlite file corrupted after http upload via powershell

Tags: powershell, sqlite, rest, http, httpwebrequest

I have this powershell script that uploads a file :

```
$URL = 'DESTINATION';

function UploadFile {
    param (
        $path,
        $filename
    )
    $LF = "`r`n";
    $fileBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($path);
    $fileEnc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('UTF-8').GetString($fileBytes);
    $boundary = [System.Guid]::NewGuid().ToString(); 

    $bodyLines = ( 
        "--$boundary",
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=`"$filename`"",
        "Content-Type: multipart/form-data$LF",
        $fileEnc,
        "--$boundary--$LF" 
    ) -join $LF;
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $URL -Method Post -ContentType "multipart/form-data; boundary=`"$boundary`"" -Body $bodyLines;   
}
```

And my file is a .sqlite database.
The issue is that even if the file is actually uploaded, the .sqlite file is corrupted and can't be read with DB Browser for example. I precise that the original file before upload is not corrupted.
I presume there must be something wrong with the readfile/upload process, but I can't see what is wrong. Can someone please help me?

Comment: You want `[Convert]::ToBase64String($fileEnc)` instead of just `$fileEnc` inside `$bodyLines`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I changed it and nothing is uploaded, lot of errors

Comment: If the file in question is not a SQL script, but is actually a binary SQLite database, why are you uploading it as utf-8 encoded text?

Comment: @Sabrebar Sorry, that should have been `[Convert]::ToBase64String($fileBytes)` - you'll want to skip/remove the `Encoding.GetString()` step completely

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen then I should change the content-type I guess?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I don't know, maybe that's my mistake

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for your answer, I can upload the file, but it is not readable. How can I precise that im uploading base64 file please?

Comment: See if https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3#example-4-simplified-multipart-form-data-submission or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-7.3#example-5-submit-a-multipart-form-data-file provides clues.

Comment: Try just uploading the file `Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -InFile $pathToFile`